# Updating Array Data in Chat Screen After Successful API Post

Tags: reactjs, class, axios, state, chat

I am working on a ReactJS application where I have implemented a chat screen. Users can type messages in a textarea, and upon clicking the "Send" button, the message is sent to the backend API. However, I am facing an issue in updating the chat array data on the front end after a successful API post.

Here is a simplified version of my ReactJS component:

```
 <div className="textarea_sec">
    <div className="btn_sec">
      <textarea
        value={this.state.chattext}
        name="chattext"
        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter your message.."
      />
          <button
            className="send-btn"
            style={{ background: this.state.disable ? "grey" : null }}
            disabled={this.state.disable}
            onClick={() => {
              this.sendMessage(this.state.chattext);
            }}
          >
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

And here is the sendMessage function that handles the API post:

sendMessage = (message) => {

  const data = {text:message};
  
  axios
    .post(BASEURL + "api/chat_post/", data, { headers })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === 'success') {
        this.setState({
          chattext: "",  // Emptying the textarea on successful post
        });
      }

      this.getChatHistory();
      this.scrollToBottom();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      toast("Post Chat API error" + error);
      console.log("Post Message metrics axios error:", error);
    });
};
```

Even though the chattext state is being reset successfully, the chat array (this.getChatHistory()) is not being updated as expected. I suspect that there might be an issue with how I am updating the state or handling the array data.

Could someone please provide insights into how I can ensure that the chat array on the frontend is properly updated after a successful API post?

Comment: Could you show the getChatHistory function? Are you calling setState there?

Comment: In getChatHistory i am setting the state of chat Array

Answer (score 1):

If you are using same state for history and for `chattext` - you may mess things. Because you replacing prev state with `{chattext:''}`.

The general pattern to update complex state would be:

```
newState = {...oldState, { chattext: ''}}
```

In this case you copying prev state first, then overriding some values.

Second issue, if you expecting some logic run after state is updated, you should put it inside `useEffect`, just move following into `useEffect` section and add dependencies that expected to affect it.

```
this.getChatHistory();
this.scrollToBottom();
```

Comment: @ Oleg Imanilov thanks for your insight, but chattext is just a string and i want to empty it when the post api is successful, so that if any api error occurs, then the user don't have to type the text again, thats what i am trying here.

Comment: @Ajith I edited the answer, see second section.